# After a system transfer, eShop purchases are no longer available to re-download

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

After a system transfer, my eShop purchases are no longer available to re-download.

How can I find my purchases to re-download?

Answer (score 3):

The eShop stores a record of all downloads and purchases, so you can redownload previously purchased software, provided the software is still available on the eShop. If it is not available, there is not really any way to get it back.

To redownload your purchases, go into the eShop.

From there, press the orange menu button in the top left corner, then scroll down and press "Settings/Other", then scroll down to the History section, and press the "Your Downloads" section.

In that section there should be a list of all of the things that you downloaded - you can press "Download" on each item, then "Download now" or "Download later" (which will mean that the 3DS will download your titles the next time it sleeps).

As Nintendo's [help page](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/3ds/en_na/gi_index.jsp) states:

> "For the most part, information on the target system (system being
>   transferred to) will be overwritten by the information on the source
>   system (system being transferred from). See below for specific
>   details, or click here for more information:
>
> All content downloaded via the eShop on both systems (DSiWare,
>   Ambassador games and status, 3DS Downloadable software, etc) will be
>   combined together onto the target system. After the transfer is
>   complete, titles will be available to re-download from the Nintendo
>   eShop. Any game data that is duplicated on both systems is overwritten
>   by the data on the source system. The eShop balance from both systems
>   is combined together. (Total amount cannot exceed $200 or the transfer
>   will be canceled.)"